# Internal modifier by default

Tags: java, kotlin

У меня есть вопросы касательно модификатора доступа в Kotlin `internal`

1. Почему было принятно решение убрать модификатор доступа `package`? ведь она тоже полезная, особенно когда архитектура приложения такая что все делится не по слоям а по фичам.
2. Можно ли как то сделать `internal` модификатор по дефолту, а `public` уже писали бы, есть ли какие либо плагины для этого?
3. Почему же `public` по дефолту? На самом деле `public` чаще используется чем package в Java, но если в Kotline есть `internal`, в модульных проектах да и даже в микросервисах, будет чаще использваться `internal`(при условии что разработчики будут заботиться о минимизации доступа)

Comment: Хотя я не знаю ответа на ваши вопросы, мне также непонятно причем тут java? И что значит `убрать модификатор доступа package` - он в котлине разве был когда то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Потому что в Kotlin пакет как таковой не несет той нагрузки которой он нес в Java. В Kotlin вы можете в одном файле поместить неограниченное количество классов или функций без объявления класса, в отличии от Java в которой любая функция должна объявляться только внутри классов. Второй момент: в Java уровень доступа protected можно обойти извне если указать для нового класса тот же пакет ( вот тут могу в способе немного ошибаться, но точно есть способ это обойти), это одна из причин почему разработчики Kotlin отказались от этого модификатора доступа.

- 2 и 3 пункты. В большинстве случаев когда мы пишем новый класс, нам нужен как раз публичный доступ, т.к. в повседневных задачах мы реже используем закрытые уровни доступа. Исключение тут несут private функции, но тут IDE вам подсветит если ваша функция нигде не будет использоваться и будет иметь public модификатор.

  Что касается разработчиков библиотек, то тут ваше замечание действительно резонно. И именно поэтому сейчас разработчики Kotlin работают над новым режимом в котором как раз все модификаторы, в том числе и public нужно будет указывать явно.

Comment: Но помещать все классы в один файл не правильно ведь, к примеру 10 классов, нужно чтобы только два из них были доступны из вне, а остальные `package` и все классы достаточно большие. Или я что то не понимаю

Comment: Ну я вам не пытался доказать что правильно, а что нет. Я просто видел несколько докладов в которых это обсуждалось с разработчиками Kotlin. Второй момент, ну может не 10 классов, но к примеру если несколько классов относятся к одному функционало то это вполне легетимно. Или к примеру модельки от одного запроса. В общем иногда это актуально.

Comment: Или к примеру 9 классов надо internal а один был бы `package`

Comment: Да, я понимаю, мне хочется понять, почему в таком важном моменте так странно сделали. Хотя во всем остальном идеально.

Comment: Ну потому что package private это тоже не безопасно и очень легко обходится. А Internal чуток замороченее работает.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду обходится в случае если это будет в библиотеке. Но мы не только библиотеки пишем. И сами тоже. То есть фактически решение что разграничение по пакету уже не актуально внутри модуля.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю что деление по пакетам уже не актуально, какая причина. То что она очень редко используется? Какая то статистика есть? Мне нужны весомые доводы чтобы на это закрыли глаза чтобы начать использовать Котлин в моей команде

Comment: Я не могу вам дать какие-то весомые доводы. Это все зависит от команды, задач и подходов. И решения принимать должны в контексте определённой команды

Comment: Как бы да, в контексте определенной команды в которых нужно привести доводы за и против. Поэтому и спрашиваю почему так сделано,  а не то как нам принять решение

Comment: Ну я понял, не понятно почему убрали, в принципе я не за то чтобы внедрить `package`. Наверное его очень редко используют и не имеет смысла его использовать, разве что для удовлетворения своего чувства чистоты

Comment: Ну я вам не дам ответ на этот вопрос. То что я знаю, я ответил в ответе